# What does it mean to write $(y,z)=G(x)$

Tags: functions

I understand this is a map from $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R^2}$.

Is it the case that $y=y(x)$ and $z=z(x)$? i.e

Are $y$ and $z$ individually functions of $x$ as well as being so jointly ($(y,z)=G(x)$)

Answer (score 1):

When $G$ is map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$, we write $G\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$. This means that $G$ takes any real number $x\in\mathbb R$ and depending on $x$ returns an element of $\mathbb R^2$, *i.e.* a **pair** of real numbers $(y,z)$. For example
\begin{align*}
G\colon \mathbb R &\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2 \\
x &\longmapsto (2x, x+1)
\end{align*}
is such a map and we have $G(1)=(2,2)$, $G(2)=(4,3)$, $G(\pi) = (2\pi, \pi+1)$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

if $\pi_1:(s,t) \mapsto s$ and $\pi_2:(s,t) \mapsto t$ are the two co-ordinate projection maps from your $\mathbb{R^2}$-frame, then the statement is saying that:

$$
y = \pi_1 \circ G(x) \\
z = \pi_2 \circ G(x) \\
$$

(emended, thanks to an error spotted by Christoph)

Comment: I assume $(y,z)=G(x)$ refers to elements, not functions. Otherwise it should have been $G=(y,z)$, no?